# Matching contours to level images - OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Is it possible to only match & level the contours in an image? Possibly symmetric matching? If so, what matcher would you use for this purpose?

**Demonstration Image:**

[image: problem]

In this image of my lovely iMac, you can see that the images passed in are unleveled. This is because I took the first image at a different height than the second image.. For example:

```
(First Image capture)
                        (Second Image capture)
```

So, instead of matching features all over the image, I was wondering if OpenCV has any feature matcher that could limit me to match the edges of where 1 image ends, and the other one begins. That way, I could hopefully straighten them up.

**What I currently use:**

- `BestOf2NearestMatcher`
- `GridAdaptedFeatureDetector` with `GFTTDetector`
- `SiftDescriptorExtractor`
- Refining with camera parameters based on features with basic OpenCV sample

**What I hope would be the result:**

My target result would be to align the images in the demonstration image above.

Comment: Google for "image stitching" ;D

Comment: That's what I've been doing for the past 6 weeks.. Have I missed something that describes my issue? @Miki

Comment: What's the result if you use https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching.cpp ?

Comment: Why would I use a built-in stitcher pipeline...... I don't think you understood my question.. I could stitch with SURF points - sure.. But, my question is, instead of matching points all across the image (which SURF/SIFT does), is it possible to limit it to the ends of the image? I.e. (ROI, x,x,500,500)

Comment: In other words, I wouldn't want to use a built in stitching pipeline. I would only want to limit the key points to the ends of the image(s).

Comment: Hmmm probably I still don't get it right... but yes, you can find keypoints on a ROI, passing a mask to the "detect" function...

Comment: Interesting.. I'll read up on the OpenCV documentation regarding this.. That might be what I'm looking for. Thanks @Miki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am kind of working on the same issue. You can surely limit the feature points using some mask. In my case I know that there is 50% overlap in adjacent images, so I have used features in later half (x > im.cols)of first image and initial half of second image(x < im.cols).You can make this changes in matchers.cpp of stitching. This will eliminate the chance of false matches.

But this will fail when there are less or no feature points. I would suggest to go for line based stitching if aligning edges of object is the main concern.

Line features in opencv3.0

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/line_descriptor/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! But, how can you pass back `KeyLine` to http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/db5/structcv_1_1detail_1_1ImageFeatures.html in order to use `BestOfTwoNearestMatcher`?

Comment: The only reason why I'm tethered to using `BestOfTwoNearestMatcher` is because it's passing back `pairwise_matches` that I could use to "refine" the camera parameters.

Comment: Actually, that was a dumb question.. I could just convert the Point2f -> KeyPoints -> Pass back to ImageFeatures -> Done :)

Comment: If your are using line features You need to change function parameters and also BestOfTwoNearestMatcher works by finding number of inliers from homography. Homography calculation for line features is different, So you need to change homography function as well. Read line-centric approach in this https://www.cs.ubc.ca/grads/resources/thesis/May09/Dubrofsky_Elan.pdf

Comment: Do you mean to use endpoints of line as keypoints? It will not give correct results. Due to noise in image endpoints may not correspond

Comment: You're 100% right. Will need to look into this further before I give my opinion on it.